# How do I install dig?

Tags: networking, package-management

How do I install `dig` (the DNS lookup tool)?  I can't figure out what the package name is.

Comment: Strange that you don't have it. Package `ubuntu-standard` directly depends on `dnsutils` which contains `dig`, `nslookup` and `nsupdate` utilities. Is your system ok? Can you try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-standard`?

Comment: You appear to have answered your own question?

Comment: ubuntu servers often do not come with dig

Comment: It's probably a "minimized" Ubuntu... the only tool left there is pretty much apt (as well as ssh/scp if you've ticked for installing SSH server), not even vi, nano nor ping! From there, the question is to find the names of the packages, dnsutils in this case.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install dnsutils
```

To find out which package a file is in you can do

```
sudo apt-cache search dig
```

Sometimes that works, but in this case it was useless.  You can search for which package a specific file is in using the 'Search the contents of packages' search form here:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Comment: As @oli said in their answer, adding keywords can make `apt-cache search` more useful; in this case the combination of `dns` and `dig` keywords returned a much smaller list (about a dozen packages) than either by itself (hundreds for `dns`, almost a thousand for `dig`).

Answer (score 253):

You can install it by opening a terminal and typing

```
sudo apt-get install dnsutils
```

Or via the *Ubuntu Software Center* by clicking bellow:

[image: Install via the software center]

For future reference, I found this out by doing a quick search with apt-cache:

```
apt-cache search dns dig
```

And then verified with `aptitude`.

Comment: A much more easier command to determine the package, provided you know complete path of file you are searching is             $ sudo dpkg -S /usr/bin/dig
dnsutils: /usr/bin/dig

Comment: @James, this command will only work if you had dig already installed, while Oli's will search all available packages.

Comment: @Jamess You can [search by filename](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=%2Fbin%2Fdig&mode=exactfilename&suite=maverick&arch=any) on packages.ubuntu.com. And FWIW, you don't need `sudo` to run `dpkg -S`.

Answer (score 9):

Another command:

```
apt-file search /usr/bin/dig
```

You should install `apt-file` and update it beforehand:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```